# Read Sentinel-2 L1C view angles from rasterio

Tags: gdal, rasterio, sentinel2

I am trying to read the view angles from a Sentinel-2 image (L1C SAFE compact format) for executing an atmospheric correction algorithm. I can get those values by parsing the file `MTD_TL.xml`, but I am not able to get them through rasterio.

I have tried to access to those data using the `xml:SENTINEL2` and the `xml:VRT` metadata domains, but I can only access to the values from the file `MTD_MSIL1C.xml` (the main metadata file).

The whole point of using rasterio is being able of using GDAL's virtual file system, as the images will be read from S3 buckets. Any alternatives for easily reading `MTD_TL.xml` through the virtual file system would be also valid (and really appreciated).

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself.

I could not find how to get the values I require, but according to https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html the function VSIFOpenL may be used for opening the file. After that, manual parsing will do the trick :)

Ps. I must read the documentation slowly.